# SwiftLint Returning Whitespace Violation

Tags: swift, swiftlint

```
var completion: (()-> Void)?

class func showView(inside view: UIView,
                        with trophy: Trophy,
                        completion:(()-> Void)? = nil) -> TrophyDetailsView {
}
```

I keep getting "Returning Whitespace Violation" in the above lines,
How do i fix it?

Comment: First do this in Xcode to see where `Editor > Show Invisibles`

Comment: For anyone else wondering var completion: (()-> Void)? to var completion: (() -> Void)?